# jQuery object from html table into two one-dimensional arrays for Chartist chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, oop, chartist.js

This may be so simple that you may find it silly, but I'm stumped. I'm fiddling around with some jQuery code that should extract data from a 2-column HTML table and then spit out two one-dimensional arrays. E.g. ['sample 1','sample 2', 'sample 3'...] for the bar tags, and e.g [645, 872, 423...] for the bar values in a [Chartist](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/) chart.

*EDIT: I later discovered that the "series" array should be bi-dimensional to permit more datasets to be presented in the same chart. If using only one "series" dataset, put brackets around it to turn it into an array within an array.*

I've managed to get the HTML table values into a jQuery object like this:

```
var tdata = [];
var headers = [];
$('#myTable th').each(function(index, item) {
headers[index] = $(item).html();
});
$('#myTable tr').has('td').each(function() {
var tdataItem = {};
$('td', $(this)).each(function(index, item) {
    tdataItem[headers[index]] = $(item).html();
});
tdata.push(tdataItem);
});
```

...where myTable is a HTML table like:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tbody><tr>
<th>Oxide</th>
<th>Proportion</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ca0</td>
<td>0.73</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Li2O</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>MgO</td>
<td>0.13</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

The problem is that I can't get the first column (under "Oxides") and the second column values (under "Proportion") into their own one-dimensional array to feed into Chartist, which basically needs this:

```
var data = {
  labels: ['CaO', 'Li2O', 'MgO'],
  series: [0.73, 0, 0.13]
    ]
};
```

I made a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gSlave/ctwLb7u6/1/) where you can see the output of the array through `console.log(tdata);`

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0:
Object
Oxide:
"Ca0"
Proportion:
"0.73"
__proto__:
Object
```

It seems that somehow these objects are multidimensional or there's some jQuery funkiness going on, because I haven't managed to extract the one-dimensional "labels" and "series" arrays for Chartist. It should be dead simple, though?

Comment: Will it always be the 2 columns or are you looking for this to be dynamic?

Comment: There will always be 2 columns for each table. There _will_ be some later complexity since various datasets should be superposed in the same chart, but I haven't run into problems with this so far with Chartist: one simply passes various series of one-dimensional arrays: 
`series: [2, 5, 3, 8],  [9, 1, 4, 5], ...` or rather
`series: valueArray1, valueArray2, ...`

Comment: Ok. Did my answer below resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may have the data backwards. You are storing an array of objects, versus an object with 2 arrays.

I update the fiddle with an example that creates the "data" object you would use for Chartist.

https://jsfiddle.net/t539uuok/1/

```
var data = {
    labels: [],
  series: []
};
$("#myTable tr").has("td").each(function () {
    data.labels.push($(this).find("td:first").html());
    data.series.push($(this).find("td:last").html());
});
```

If you need it to be dynamic, there would need to be other changes. But, this would work if you are only looking to capture 1-dimensional label/series data.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is very elegant and efficient. Now I ran into another issue: Chartist doesn't swallow strings in the "series" array and also throws an error where there are any empty places in that array (which there will always be).
I've added parseFloat like this:
`data.series.push(parseFloat($(this).find("td:last").html()));`
but how to solve the empty places problem?

Comment: Oops I also realised that there may be three columns sometimes.

Comment: Yes, parseFloat is definitely the way to go. The only change I would make is to use a conditional to make sure you get a 0 instead of NaN. For example, var val = parseFloat($(this).find("td:last").html()); data.series.push(isNaN(val) ? 0 : val);

Comment: I was fiddling with an if statement to check if it's an empty string "" but your coding is much more concise ;-)

Comment: Perfect, very nice. I'm marking this question as answered and have upvoted. It says "Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score." so maybe you won't see it. 
Thanks again!

Comment: Btw a correction, for those also battling with Chartist and who've found this particular solution here. **Chartist does not accept "series" as one-dimensional**, probably since more datasets are usually added. If using only one dataset, convert it to bi-dimensional:
   `var data = {
        labels: data.labels,
        series:[data.series] 
    };`